# show the contents of a folder in a web page

Tags: php, web-deployment

I'm trying to build an online storage site similar to Google drive. My code can upload files and save it in a specific given path. It also has code for creating files. the only thing is missing is showing the user "how many" or "which" files he/she uploaded in the specific path.

As shown in the Google drive image (in the link below), I want my code to look like similar to this, I want my user to see he/she's uploaded files in a serial on the web page. I'm not sure how to do it or whether it is possible in php or not, or if it is possible in php then which function is needed. I'm also not sure "what to type" in the Google search to find some examples of this type of coding.  please tell me anything that will help me to start this part of my project.

http://www.google.com.bd/imgres?sa=X&biw=1024&bih=605&tbm=isch&tbnid=kSX8G1DGHuYiHM:&imgrefurl=http://www.zdnet.com/blog/networking/free-storage-for-you-google-drive-to-arrive-today/2293&docid=VGLnSQuNf4vGLM&imgurl=http://www.zdnet.com/i/story/62/58/002293/google-drive.png&w=1012&h=725&ei=JPCNUtj_FoKtrAfYkoHwCA&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:12,s:0,i:122&iact=rc&page=2&tbnh=173&tbnw=241&start=8&ndsp=14&tx=182&ty=107

(I'm still working  offline. I haven't yet launched it online.)
if you need any code from my existing work please tell me. I would love to upload my code.

---thanks.

Comment: Are saving files just on the disk or you store names in a DB?

Comment: the files are saved directly on the hard disk of my pc. in here, C:\abcd\sss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you can just insert records in the Database while uploading (saving/moving files).

And example pseudocode, as you didn't provide any, would be:

```
if (checkForErrors()) {
    // your error page for file exists, improper extension, and other violated constraints
} else {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'your/path/here/' . $_FILES['file']['name']);
    $db->query("INSERT INTO uploads (uploader, filename, uploaded_on) VALUES ('{$_SESSION['username']}', '{$_FILES['file']['name']}', NOW());");
}
// later you can just fetch the results for the current uploaded
$db->query("SELECT filename, uploaded_on FROM uploads WHERE uploader = '{$_SESSION['username']}';");
// under the row of filename will be stored the files that the current user has uploaded
```